# Jboss LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jboss, jaxb

I have two war files: A and B with web services using CXF

A uses web service in B.

B uses web service in A.

Everything is working fine in Tomcat. But when i deployed in Jboss, i am  facing linkage error.

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createDispatch(Ljavax/xml/ws/EndpointReference;Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBContext;Ljavax/xml/ws/Service$Mode;[Ljavax/xml/ws/WebServiceFeature;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Dispatch;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/cxf/jaxws/ServiceImpl, and its superclass loader (instance of ), have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext used in the signature

I have removed jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar and jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar from the war and tested. Still i am facing the same issue.

What is the reason? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of JBoss you are using, there would be a version of jaxb jars included with it. Check your JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base folder.

If you want JBoss to ignore the jars it has and use your applications' instead, you will need to explicitly tell it to do so. This can be done using custom modules:

1. Create a folder inside JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/`<folder_name>`/main/ and put your jars in it.
2. Create a module.xml file in this folder and list down all the jar names as `<resource-root>` .
3. Create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in your web project's WEB-INF directory and list this custom module here.

For more details, check this link:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: Thanks for you post. i will try and come back

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Sampada - I'm having a similar issue I have the jars bundled in my EJB jar, deployed within an EAR and use the jboss-deployment-structure way of doing it, everythings fine upon deployment but on a restart of the server i get the "loader constraint violation" - any idea why this might be ocurring and how to resolve it?  It seems strange it works when deployed but then appears to be ignored on server startup.